# Why does my recursive code result in a stack overflow error?

Tags: c++, max-heap

This code is given in the book "Introduction to Algorithms". For this I used 1 indexed array

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int n=6;
int x[1000];

void max_heapify(int a[],int i)
{
    int left=2*i;
    int right=2*i+1;
    int largest=i;
    if( left<=n && a[left]>a[largest]){
        largest=left;

    }
    if(right<=n &&  a[right]>a[largest])
    {
        largest=right;

    }
    if(largest!=i)
    {
        int t=a[i];
        a[i]=a[largest];
        a[largest]=t;

    }
    max_heapify(a,largest);
}
void max_heap(int a[])
{
    int heap_length=n;
    for(int i=n/2;i>=1;i--)
        max_heapify(a,i);

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>x[i];
    max_heap(x);
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<x[i]<<"  ";
    // system("PAUSE");
    //return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    return 0;
}
```

For this input

```
1 5 7 8 3 9
```

on ideone.com it writes "time limit exceeded". I have tried the debugger in Visual Studio, with the following result

```
First-chance exception at 0x001c14d9 in max_heap.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
Unhandled exception at 0x001c14d9 in max_heap.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
First-chance exception at 0x001c14d9 in max_heap.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x002c0ffc.
Unhandled exception at 0x001c14d9 in max_heap.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x002c0ffc.
The program '[6044] max_heap.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? I mean really debugging, not just running in a debug mode? Step by step operation etc. Your recursion is probably too deep, debug your recursive function to find out why it doesn't stop when you expect it to.

Answer (score 6):

Your `max_heapify` will always end up in another recursion. There is no termination happening in any of the control paths. This causes your stack overflow.

Comment: but on wikipedia it is described so

Comment: I assume you mean [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)? Then no, it's not. There the recursive call only happens as part of the last if statement. In your code it always happens.

Comment: because it is pseudo code,i could not understand when is end point of if statment

Comment: one question  esle,during the algorithm of heapsort,i dont understand what mmeaning has   heap_size?

Comment: `heap_size`? I don't see where you get that from. Anyway, that is a different question.